# Using Ajax to Updating Multiple Items in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

Am having problem for updating quantity_received details using po_id and item_id using Ajax with code igniter. My problem is that is when i update the po_id =5 and item_id= 1 the quantity_received details are updated. Again when i updating the second item po_id=5 and item_id=2  then the quantity_received details are not get updated, also  the same values had been updated which i was in the item_id=1..

```
    My code:

   <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered mytable order-table" id="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>PO Id</th>
                    <th style="width:0px;">Item Id</th>
                    <th>Item Name</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Add RO</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Action</th>
                 </tr>
            </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                             foreach ($pitems as $result)
                             {
                        ?>
                    <tr class="">
                         <td><input type="text" disabled name="po_id" id="po_id" value="<?php echo $result->po_id; ?>"/></td>
                         <td><input type="text" disabled name="item_id" id="item_id" value="<?php echo $result->item_id; ?>"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" disabled name="item_name" id="item_name" value="<?php echo $result->item_name; ?>"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" disabled name="quantity_purchased" id="quantity_purchased" value="<?php echo $result->quantity_purchased; ?>"/></td>
                         <td><input type="text"   name="quantity_received" id="quantity_received" required placeholder="Enter Received Items" value="<?php echo $result->quantity_received; ?>"/></td>

                         <!--td><span class="action"><a href="#" id="<?php echo  $result->po_id.'/'.$result->item_id; ?>" class="delete" title="Delete">X</a></span></td-->
                         <td><span class="action"><a href="#" id="<?php echo  $result->po_id.'/'.$result->item_id.'/'.$result->quantity_purchased.'/'.$_POST['quantity_received']; ?>" class="edit" title="Edit">Add</a></span></td>

                           <?php
                               }
                               ?>

                             </tbody>
                          </table>
```

Ajax:

```
    $(".edit").click(function(){

    var element = $(this);
    var del_id = element.attr("id");
    var arr = del_id.split('/');
    var quantity_purchased = $('#quantity_purchased').val();
    var quantity_received = $('#quantity_received').val();
    var del_id1 = element.attr("id");

      if(confirm("Are you sure you want to Edit this?"))
      {

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                 url: "<?php echo base_url().'/inventory_c/ro_edit_poid11' ?>",
                cache: false,
                data: 'po_id='+arr[0]+'&item_id='+arr[1]+'&quantity_received='+quantity_received,

                dataType: "html",
                success: function(htmldata) {
                alert("success");

                   }
                 });

                   }
       return false;
            });
```

My controller fun:

```
      public function ro_edit_poid11() 
      {
     $po_id = $_POST['po_id'];
     $item_number = $_POST['item_id'];
     $quantity_received = $_POST['quantity_received'];
     $last_id= $po_id;
        $edit_temp_purchase = array( 
                  'quantity_received' => $quantity_received,
                );

              $this->db->where(array('po_id' => $po_id, 'item_id' => $item_number));
              $this->db->update('bgs_po_list_items', $edit_temp_purchase);
        [enter image description here][1]
 }
```

pls do my needs @Thanks

Comment: give the function from where the $pitems variable is coming.

Comment: my controller fun:                                                                                     $data['pitems'] = $this->inventory_m->purchase_items_update($po_id);         MY model fun:    function purchase_items_update($po_id)
 {
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('bgs_po_list_items AS T1');
  $this->db->where('T1.po_id',$po_id);
  $query = $this->db->get();   
  return $query->result();
 }

Comment: all the values from db which respected id is coming correctly. when i edit first value it gets updated correctly, also want to edit second values is not updated correctly. (it takes first values which i was entered in item1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a different id to the following 2 input boxes

```
<td><input type="text" disabled name="quantity_purchased" id="quantity_purchased_<?php echo $result->po_id; ?>_<?php echo $result->item_id; ?>" value="<?php echo $result->quantity_purchased; ?>"/></td>
<td><input type="text"   name="quantity_received" id="quantity_received_<?php echo $result->po_id; ?>_<?php echo $result->item_id; ?>" required placeholder="Enter Received Items" value="<?php echo $result->quantity_received; ?>"/></td>
```

Then get the values of quantity purchase and reveived in your jquery as follows:

```
$(document).on('click','a.edit',function(){
var element = $(this);
var del_id = element.prop("id");
var arr = del_id.split('/');

var po_id = parseInt(arr[0]);
var item_id = parseInt(arr[1]);
var quantity_purchased = $('#quantity_purchased_'+po_id+'_'+item_id).val();
var quantity_received = $('#quantity_received_'+po_id+'_'+item_id).val();

var del_id1 = element.attr("id");

  if(confirm("Are you sure you want to Edit this?"))
  {

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
             url: "<?php echo base_url().'/test/ro_edit_poid11' ?>",
            cache: false,
            data: 'po_id='+arr[0]+'&item_id='+arr[1]+'&quantity_received='+quantity_received,

            dataType: "html",
            success: function(htmldata) {
            alert("success");
        }
    });
}     
});
```

And in php function return an echo for ajax to work

```
  public function ro_edit_poid11() 
  {
 $po_id = $_POST['po_id'];
 $item_number = $_POST['item_id'];
 $quantity_received = $_POST['quantity_received'];
 $last_id= $po_id;
    $edit_temp_purchase = array( 
              'quantity_received' => $quantity_received,
            );

          $this->db->update('bgs_po_list_items',$edit_temp_purchase,['po_id' => $po_id, 'item_id' => $item_number]);
    echo 'success';
}
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: ya its working @ Thanks dude.

Comment: @user3839366  give a vote please.